# How to deal with subscriptions using PayPal's REST SDK

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to create a basic subscription service on my site and I am not sure of a standard way to deal with subscriptions. I'm sure I could hack something together but I'm just wondering if there is a suggested way.

1. So I have created a [billing plan](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/) and activated it.
2. I have a subscribe button on my site that creates a [billing agreement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-agreement/) referring to the billing plan created in step 1 and redirects the user to the PayPal website were they can login and accept the subscription.
3. Once the user completes the actions on the PayPal website they are returned back to my site with a token were I then execute the agreement using the returned token from PayPal as per the documentation.

So I guess after these steps the subscription is created for that user, is active and the first payment is made immediately.

In my database, I have a field for each user names `subscribed` and it's value is a `boolean` which I set to true once they are returned to my site and the execute command is successful.

My problem is keeping this `boolean` value up to date for each user as this is the value I check to see if they can access the content.

Canceling - I can provide a cancel button on my site to cancel their subscription and when successful I can set the value to `false`. But what if they cancel through the PayPal website? I think there is a webhook names `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED` which may send me the agreement ID and If I save it in my database I can see which user it belongs to and set their subscription to `false`.

After the first month has passed and the next payment is due, is there a webhook sent for a successful payment or a failed payment so I can then set the subscription value accordingly? I see there is a webhook named `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` but I don't know if this fired for a successful payment and `PAYMENT.SALE.DENIED` for a failed payment. If these webhooks exist for subscriptions I imagine it should be a simple solution to keeping this subscribed value up to date.

Hope this made some sense.

Comment: Not sure about Webhooks works with REST API. For recurring payment, Please enable Instant payment notification(IPN) on your Business(seller) PayPal account profile settings. IPN Setup: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/, IPN Sample: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples. IPN Variable: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/